# Macro si el valor de mi celda es superior a

Tags: vba

Estoy haciendo una macro con excel y necesito comprobar si un numero de la selecion de mis celdas es mayor que otro para salir del bucle pero vba no me deja almacenar el valor en una variable para comprobarla. Simpre me dice que hay un desbordamiento al almacenar la variable,He hecho

```
Sub compara()

Dim micelda As Range
Dim checkNum As String
Dim entero As Integer
For Each micelda In Selection

checkNum = micelda.offset(0,0).value


If checkNum > 999999 Then
    MsgBox "esta campo es mayor que 999999"
End If
Next micelda

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He probado con un libro que en la columna "A" tiene valores desde 1 a 10 y a mi me funciona. He modificado algo tu código, como hago algunas cosas en VBA para diferentes versiones de Office trato de evitar referenciar la "Microsoft Excel Object Library"

```
Sub compara()
Dim app As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim ws As Object
Dim micelda As Object
Dim rango As Object
Dim checkNum As String
Dim entero As Integer

Set app = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set wb = app.workbooks.Open("C:\temp\x1.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.sheets(1)

Set rango = ws.range("A2:A10")

For Each micelda In rango
    checkNum = micelda.offset(0, 0).Value
If checkNum > 5 Then
    Debug.Print "este campo es mayor que 5 -->" & micelda.Address
End If
Next micelda

Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
app.Quit
Set app = Nothing
```

End Sub